# Python pandas: flag duplicate rows

Tags: python, pandas, duplicates

I am using the following code to denote duplicate rows

```
df['duplicate']=df.Column_A.duplicated()
```

However, when I look at the df, I see the following:

```
Column_A | duplicate
AAA        False
ABC        False
ABC        True
```

I need row 2 to also be True, so that I can filter the row "duplicate" easily. How can I accomplish that?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As per the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html) use the `keep` argument and set as `False`. As you can see it defaults to `first`.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Column_A': ['AAA', 'AAB', 'AAB', 'AAC']})
df['duplicate'] = df.duplicated(keep=False)

print(df)

     Column_A  duplicate
0    'AAA'     False
1    'AAB'     True
2    'AAB'     True
3    'AAC'     False
```

Answer (score 5):

I imagine myself lost in the wilderness and all I have to survive is `pd.factorize` and `np.bincount`
*Please, don't accept this answer*

```
f, u = pd.factorize(df.Column_A.values)
df.assign(duplicate=np.bincount(f)[f] > 1)

  Column_A  duplicate
0      AAA      False
1      ABC       True
2      ABC       True
```